# Convert number format based if locale is en_GB for entire WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a bilingual WordPress project which is translated with TranslatePress plugin. Sadly TranslatePress ignores all number fields and won't let me change their values depending on the countries number format. The offiical support team told me, it's not possible at this moment.

The original language of the page is German and the second language is English. The page contains a lot of number information for cities etc. which are put in like this 13.502.552 Since TranslatePress won't let me convert these numbers by hand I'm looking for a way to convert them for the entire site maybe through functions.php, is this possible? Is there a way to check if locale is set to en_GB and to convert all the numbers to 13,502,552 on the fly?

I already came across number_format_i18n, but could not find a way to use it properly for my purpose.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you talking about, when you say the page “contains” these numbers? Are we talking specific _meta fields_ of some sort of post type that just hold one such numeric value, or just numbers occurring anywhere inside of regular WYSIWYG text field contents, or …?

Comment: the latter, just numbers that are input via regular WISYWYG editor, no specific meta or custom fields

Comment: Well then you will probably have to write your own function to hook into the applicable filters (mainly `the_content`, might need others as well, depending on how exactly theme and/or plugins output their stuff), and then search & replace those numbers via regular expressions.

Comment: Ok, I have no clue how to do that. That's why I was looking for help over here.

Comment: Well then you’ll have to start _getting clue_ … Both the WordPress hook / filter system, as well as regular expressions, are broadly documented on the net. We’re happy to help once it comes to specific questions with a piece of code you have written; but this site is not a code-writing service.

Comment: yeah, I knew you're pointing in that direction. I hear you, although your clarification may be overshooting the mark a bit :)